# Angular interpolation calls the method many times

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

In the Angular 4,

*app.component.html*

```
<div>Counter: {{GetCount()}}</div>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
        export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
    constructor() {

      }

     ngOnInit()
     {

     }
   counter:number = 1;

  GetCount(): any {

    this.counter++;
    return this.counter;

  }
}
```

*My output was on the screen:*

**Counter: 4**

How it is possible? I am calling the GetCount method only once in my html and It's hitting 4 times when I put break point in the method.
What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Probably the event bubbling up through propagation.

Comment: I believe what is happening is your method gets triggered through change detection cycles 3 times and that makes it increment the value upto 4.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong. Angular calls your expressions multiple times in order to check if value changed.

Answer (score 2):

when you call a method like that from the html, every angular change detection cycle this method gonna call.

if you want to call this method only once, i suggest call it from the `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit(){
      GetCount()
}
 counter:number = 1;

 GetCount(): void{    
   this.counter++;     
 }
```

in the html print the couter variable

```
<div>Counter: {{counter}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular is gonna evaluate that expression every time it checks for changes, which is associated with the `DoCheck` lifecycle hook.